# How do I use /kill to kill Mooshrooms with a specific name and within a certain radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been working on a machine and require the command to kill all Mooshrooms with a certain name and in a specific radius. I have tried:

```
/kill @e[type=Mooshroom,r=(radius),name=(name)]
/kill @e[type=Mushroom_Cow,r=(radius),name=(name)]
/kill @e[type=Mushroom_cow,r=(radius),name=(name)]
/kill @e[type=MushroomCow,r=(radius),name=(name)]
```

And none work. The command `/kill @e[type=MushroomCow]` seems to work in chat, but not in command blocks.

Now, I don't actually mind about the name too much, so if anyone could tell me the command to just kill Mooshrooms within a certain radius, that would be great thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as commands that work in chat but not in command blocks. Make sure that command blocks actually work by testing with something simple like `/say test`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so how do I actually kill Mooshrooms with a specific name?

Answer (score 1):

The following command, which you have given in your question, should work:

```
/kill @e[type=MushroomCow,r=(radius),name=(name)]
```

If it does not, then it is not the command itself causing the problem. Make sure that:

- You are correctly typing/copying the command
- You are replacing `(radius)` and `(name)` with an integer number and string without spaces respectively, e.g:
  `/kill @e[type=MushroomCow,r=10,name=Dave]`
- The entities you are trying to target are within 10 blocks **of the command block**, have the name you are entering, and are MushroomCows.
- The MushroomCows have proper UUIDs (should only be a problem if they're summoned in and you've messed with it)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the commands `/kill @e[type=(Custom Name Here)]` or `/kill @e[name=(Custom Name Here)]` might work.